# Самоподписанный сертификат SSL с nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, docker-compose

Есть a docker-compose, который поднимает приложение, БД и nginx, вот собственно сам файл:

```
services:
  app:
    ...
  mongodb:
    ...
  nginx:
    image: localImageForNginx // используется образ, собранный по dockerfile'у в конце поста
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
    volumes:
    - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    links:
      - app
```

При добавлении самоподписанного сертификата SSL в конфиг nginx происходит ошибка, вот конфиг nginx:

```
#HTTP
...

#HTTPS
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        ssl_certificate     fvikk.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key fvikk.key;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://app:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static {
        access_log   off;
        expires      30d;
        alias /app/static;
    }


}
```

А вот ошибка в логах контейнера с nginx'ом:

```
[emerg] 1#1: cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/fvikk.crt": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/fvikk.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/fvikk.crt": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/fvikk.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

Проверяю по адресу и вижу, что файлы на месте:

```
# ls /etc/nginx
fvikk.crt  fvikk.key
```

Файлы сертификата и все директории по пути имеют разрешение 777, не могу понять в чем проблема, что я делаю не так?

Отредактировано: Dockerfile из которого собирался nginx

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./fvikk.crt /etc/nginx/fvikk.crt
COPY ./fvikk.key /etc/nginx/fvikk.key
```

Comment: Что-то я не вижу где у вас эти файлы попадают в контейнер

Comment: @AlexeyTen nginx собирался из своего докерфайла, там копируется

Comment: `image: nginx:latest` — насколько я понимаю эта строчка говорит взять стандартный образ nginx, а не тот который вы собрали

Comment: @AlexeyTen Метка кривая, прошу прощения, используется образ, который собран по dockerfil'у в конце

Comment: docker-compose может получить образ либо через директиву image - и тогда он скачает образ из удалённого репозитория, либо через директиву build в которой нужно указать контекст и путь к докерфайлу. у вас прописана директива image, так что вопреки вашим ожиданиям докерфайл никак не участвует в сборке контейнера

Comment: @muturgan чтобы были более понятны мои потуги переписал docker-compose, образ уже собран и вместо nginx:latest используется именно он

Comment: @lwh чтобы потуги были понятны ещё яснее, укажите пожалуйста команду которой собираете и тэгируете образ

Comment: @lwh попробуйте указать полный путь к сертификату в конфиге nginx -

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose` может получить образ либо через директиву `image` - и тогда он скачает образ из удалённого репозитория, либо через директиву `build` в которой нужно указать контекст и путь к докерфайлу. у вас прописана директива image, так что вопреки вашим ожиданиям в вашем примере докерфайл никак не участвует в сборке контейнера.

Предлагаю переписать `docker-compose.yml` приблизительно следующим образом:

```
services:
  app:
    ...
  mongodb:
    ...
  nginx:
    build:
      context: . # ищи в той же папке где лежит docker-compose.yml
      dockerfile: Dockerfile # можно не писать т.к. Dockerfile это значение по умолчанию. Но может пригодиться если название докерфайла нестандартное.
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
    volumes:
    - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    links:
      - app
```

Либо качать образ с удаленного репозитория и пробросить файлы сертификатов в контейнер:

```
services:
  app:
    ...
  mongodb:
    ...
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
    volumes:
    - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./fvikk.crt /etc/nginx/fvikk.crt
    - ./fvikk.key /etc/nginx/fvikk.key
    links:
      - app
```

Comment: все та же ошибка

Comment: @lwh в обоих вариантах конфига?